# Asignar un valor predeterminado a un select de manera dinamica mediante otro select, con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer que si se selecciona en un campo país (País de Nacimiento o País de Residencia) un valor diferente a *Venezuela*, en el otro campo país cargar el valor *Venezuela* (País de Nacimiento o País de Residencia).
Es decir, al menos 1 debe ser *Venezuela* y se debe permitir modificar.

Este es mi código:

```
var paisResidencia = document.getElementById("pais_recidencia_dato_ingreso_html");
var paisNacimiento = document.getElementById("pais_nacimiento_dato_ingreso_html");

for (var i = 1; i <= cantidadpersonas; i++) {
  if (paisResidencia === "VENEZUELA") {
    paisNacimiento.value = paisNacimiento.value;
  }
  else if (paisResidencia !== "VENEZUELA") {
    paisNacimiento.value = "VENEZUELA";
  }
  else {
    paisNacimiento.value = "VENEZUELA";
  }
}
```

solo entra al "else if".

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Muestra un [repro] del problema en cuestión, ya que no sabemos qué datos contienen los select que mencionas.

Comment: Tienes código HTML asignado? recuerda adjuntar un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), necesitamos reproducir tu código para identificar con mayor facilidad el problema, saludos.

Comment: que entre al ``else if`` o al ``else`` es exactamente lo mismo porque le estas diciendo que asigne ``"VENEZUELA"`` a ``paisNacimiento.value``. y si entra al ``if`` (falta codigo para saber porque no entra, probablemente tengas la palabra con alguna minúscula?) directamente no haría nada porque hace una re asignacion con el dato que ya tiene guardado, no tiene sentido.